# Flutter Errors in cmd

Tags: cmd, flutter

I'm a flutter newbie. I've installed flutter in program files and set the path also. When I run command 'flutter' in cmd two thing happens. In admin cmd it runs but in the normal cmd it just tickles. Nothing is there. I tried four-five times and waited for about 20 minutes but there is nothing in cmd. What is the problem?[The image of my user cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwblI.png)

Comment: Which directory did you install Flutter to?

Comment: C:\Program Files

Answer (score 1):

https://flutter.io/setup-windows/#get-the-flutter-sdk

> do not install flutter in a directory like C:\Program Files\ that requires elevated privileges).